# Respondent and Total users Count in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, mongodb-atlas

I want to write a query to return active user and total count(both active and inactive) in mongodb. I am able to run them as two separate scripts but how to retrieve the same information in one script.

Here are the collection info,

Collection: Survey

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64a640d9ab2e42c22f7eb5bd"
  },
  "companyId": {
    "$numberInt": "1007"
  },
  "userId": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "title": "Employee Holiday survey",
  "short_description": "Employee Holiday Survey",
  "description": "For the chance to win one of our ten fitness tracking bracelets please answer the following questions!!. This is a very quick survey! 4 questions and it only takes an average of two minutes.",
  "users": "all",
  "startDate": "2023-02-27",
  "endDate": "2023-02-27",
  "questions": [
    {
      "title": "What do you, as a employee, look for most when planning a holiday?",
      "type": "multipleSelect",
      "short_description": "",
      "description": "",
      "options": [
        "Countryside",
        "Partying",
        "Meeting new people",
        "Food and Drink",
        "Creating memories with friends",
        "Relaxation"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": " Would the idea of luggage transfers from one hotel to another interest you?",
      "type": "yesNo",
      "short_description": "",
      "description": "",
      "options": [
        "Yes",
        "No"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "Created",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1688617177499"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1688617177499"
    }
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "updatedBy": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "isActive": {
    "$numberInt": "1"
  },
  "isDelete": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  }
}
```

Collection: survey_response

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "9ab2e4264a640d9a2c22f7eb5bd"
  },
  "userId": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "respondentDetails": {
    "id": {
      "$numberInt": "3524152"
    },
    "business_unit_id": {
      "$numberInt": "570"
    },
    "firstName": "Ranjeet",
    "lastName": "Bandi",
    "companyID": {
      "$numberInt": "1007"
    },
    "companyEmail": "Ranjeet.Bandi@******.com",
    "employee_code": "107"
  },
  "respondentId": {
    "$numberInt": "3524152"
  },
  "surveyId": {
    "$oid": "64a640d9ab2e42c22f7eb5bd"
  },
  "companyId": {
    "$numberInt": "1007"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1688617177650"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1688617177650"
    }
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "updatedBy": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "status": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  },
  "isActive": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  },
  "isDelete": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  }
}

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "e42cdd40d9ab2e42c22f7eb5bd"
  },
  "userId": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "respondentDetails": {
    "id": {
      "$numberInt": "3524152"
    },
    "business_unit_id": {
      "$numberInt": "570"
    },
    "firstName": "Ranjeet",
    "lastName": "Bandi",
    "companyID": {
      "$numberInt": "1007"
    },
    "companyEmail": "Ranjeet.Bandi@******.com",
    "employee_code": "107"
  },
  "respondentId": {
    "$numberInt": "3524152"
  },
  "surveyId": {
    "$oid": "64a640d9ab2e42c22f7eb5bd"
  },
  "companyId": {
    "$numberInt": "1007"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1688617177650"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1688617177650"
    }
  },
  "createdBy": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "updatedBy": {
    "$numberInt": "3543573"
  },
  "status": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  },
  "isActive": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  },
  "isDelete": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  }
}
```

Expecting result:

```
{
            "_id": "64b02dbb3683c2eb891bd371",
            "companyId": 1007,
            "userId": 3543573,
            "title": "Employee Holiday survey",
            "short_description": "Employee Holiday Survey",
            "description": "For the chance to win one of our ten fitness tracking bracelets please answer the following questions!!. This is a very quick survey! 4 questions and it only takes an average of two minutes.",
            "startDate": "2023-02-27",
            "endDate": "2023-02-27",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "title": "What do you, as a employee, look for most when planning a holiday?",
                    "type": "multipleSelect",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "options": [
                        "Countryside",
                        "Partying",
                        "Meeting new people",
                        "Food and Drink",
                        "Creating memories with friends",
                        "Relaxation"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": " Would the idea of luggage transfers from one hotel to another interest you?",
                    "type": "yesNo",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "options": [
                        "Yes",
                        "No"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user_list_file": "survey/1007/User_Data_20230713-170042.xlsx",
            "status": "Created",
            "createdAt": "2023-07-13T17:00:43.357Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-07-13T17:00:43.357Z",
            "createdBy": 3543573,
            "updatedBy": 3543573,
            "isActive": 1,
            "isDelete": 0,
            "stat": {
                "totalSurveyUser": 50,
                "responseCount": 10
            }
        }
```

Currently i'm using this query,

```
.aggregate([
        { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
        { $match: queryConditions },
        {
          $lookup:
          {
            from: COLLECTION_RESPONSE,
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'surveyId',
            as: 'responseDetails',
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { status: 1 } },
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            stat_responseCount: {
              $size: "$responseDetails"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot:
            {
              $mergeObjects:
                [
                  "$$ROOT", {
                    status: {
                      $concat: [
                        { $toUpper: { $substr: ["$status", 0, 1] } },
                        { $substr: ["$status", 1, { $strLenCP: "$status" }] }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "responseDetails": 0
          }
        }
      ])
```

Please suggest the better way